Suppressing 'sync' compiler errors in app with no async
I am trying to share a reference (assigned once) between objects in an application that is single-threaded. I have been trying to use core::cell::OnceCell, but I receive a compiler error that:
OnceCell<Peripherals> cannot be shared between threads safely [E0277] Help: the trait Sync is not implemented for OnceCell<Peripherals> Note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use std::sync::OnceLock instead Note: shared static variables must have a type that implements Sync
Async is not used anywhere in the application, it is going to run on a single core 8-bit processor and thus no_std so std::sync derivatives are a no-go. Surely the answer can't be that async is always assumed, how can this be assumed on small resource constrained microprocessors?
EDIT: In case anyone wonders about 'hidden' async implemented somewhere I forgot about or something, this is has been pared down to just the program entry function that currently only instantiates these variables.

It looks like you mean "multi-threading" instead of "async". They are orthogonal; async/.await machinery can work on a single thread and avoid Sync requirement. The Sync/Send traits are specifically about inter-thread usage.

What are you doing that incurs the "Sync is not implemented for ..." error? Simply declaring a variable and using its reference doesn't require Sync.

@kmdreko that is literally it. I am setting the contents of the OnceCell: _ = DEVICE.set(Peripherals::take().unwrap());

Are you using a static variable? Those would need to be Sync regardless.

It is. Why would static need to be Sync if it is not mutable or accessed in some asynchronous way?

This was asked recently here: The concept of a single-threaded program doesn't exist to Rust

Also: Are mutable static primitives actually unsafe if single-threaded?

God that is a nightmare... but I guess I get it. Thanks for the answer!

@kmdreko How is OnceCell used at all in that case? I guess you could wrap it in a mutex but then I'm not sure why that wouldn't be the default
